# Ruby grep, match and return

Tags: ruby, grep

Is there anyway to check if a value exist in a file without ALWAYS going through entire file ?

Currently I used:

```
if open('file.txt').grep(/value/).length > 0
  puts "match"
else 
  puts "no match"
end
```

But it's not efficient as I only want to know whether it exists or not. Really appreciate a solution with grep / others similar one-liner.

Please note the "ALWAYS" before down-vote my question

Comment: And how exactly do you plan to check if a file contains a value without going through the entire file?

Comment: @Tempos: for example, if the value is at the beginning of the file, I want it to return immediately after seeing it

Comment: No matter how you put it, you have to go over the whole file, at least once.

Comment: @Tempos: why ? If in normal implementation, "while (until eof) if (thisline == 'x') then closefile and return" rather than "while( until eof ) do if (thisline =='x') record and next", is it still not clear to you ? If there is no value, yes it will run entire file, but if there is multiple value, it only read the file until the first value found

Comment: So write a method that does it line-by-line (assuming your pattern can't cross line boundaries)--easy enough.

Comment: @iKid, the algorithm to check will go through the whole file on the scenario that the value doesn't exist. This was what I was trying to say.

Comment: @Tempos: Yes I know, that's why my question is "without always going through entire file" Notice the "ALWAYS"

Comment: @Dave Newton: I'm asking a feature of grep or a one-liner, I can easily write for loop, please check my question

Comment: Going through line-by-line would be a one-liner too, or you could use find. Basically you're asking why "grep", which finds all matches, finds all matches.

Comment: Can you write a neat one liner with "Going through line-by-line" ? to replace my "if open('file.txt').grep(/value/).length > 0" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want line-by-line comparison using a one-liner:

```
matches = open('file.txt') { |f| f.lines.find { |line| line.include?("value") } }
puts matches ? "yes" : "naaw"
```

Comment: the puts seems to break it (as I didn't specify parenthesis around the if).

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the only way you can tell if an arbitrary expression exists in a file is by going over the file and looking for it. If you're looking for the first instance, then on average you'll be scanning half the file until you find your expression when it's there. If the expression isn't there then you'll have to scan the entire file to figure that out.

You could implement that in a one-liner by scanning the file line-by-line. Use `IO.foreach`

If you do this often, then you can make the search super efficient by indexing the file first, e.g. by using Lucene. It's a trade-off - you still have to scan the file, but only once since you save it's content in a more search-friendly data structure. However, if you don't access a given file very frequently, it's probably not worth the overhead - implementation, maintenance and extra storage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ruby one-liner that will work from the linux command line to perform a grep on a text file, and stop on first found.

```
ruby -ne '(puts "first found on line #{$.}"; break) if $_ =~ /regex here/' file.txt
```

-n gets each line in the file and feeds it to the global variable $_

$. is a global variable that stores the current line number

If you want to find all lines matching the regex, then:

```
ruby -ne 'puts "found on line #{$.}" if $_ =~ /regex here/' file.txt
```